# In django, can you have 2 controller actions with the same name but different POST types?

Tags: django

In django, can I have 2 controller actions with the same name, but one for the 'get' request and 1 for the 'post' request?

If not, what is the best-practice for this type of scenerio?

i.e.

say I have a login action and view, should the form post go to another action with a different name or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing Django views (you call them controllers) you can distinguish what type of request are you serving. Taken from the docs (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    do_something()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    do_something_else()
```